# laravel - create validate with required_without and required_if

Tags: php, laravel

How create validate for form which looking something like this: If user select 'old car' radio button option he need select car name from dopdown select list and then he doesn't have to complete the remaining fields. If user select 'new car' radio button option he must insert name of car and number. If the car doesn't have number user need select checkbox 'car without number' and then he will only have to enter the car name. Right now it's not work as I would like.

```html
<form action="/action.php">
  <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Cars:</label><br>
  <div id="option" role="radiogroup">          
  <input id="opt" type="radio" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="old" name="car" checked>Old car                  
 <input id="opt" type="radio" class="form-control form-control-sm" value="new" name="car">New car                  
 </div>
<div id="old_car">
{!! Form::select('car', $cars, null, ['class'=>'form-control form-control-sm form-control-chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Choose']) !!}
{!! $errors->first('bu', '<strong><p style="color:red;" class="help-block">:message</p></strong>') !!}
</div>
<div id="new_car">
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Car:</label><br>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="name" type="text"><br>
<label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Car number:</label><br>
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="car_number" id="number"><br> 
{!! Form::checkbox('no_number', null, false,  ['class'=>'form-check-input', 'id'=>'car']); !!}
<label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">car without number</label>                
</div>              
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

```php
class CarController

...

public function store(Request $request)
{
      $request->validate([            
            'car' => ['required_if:car,old', 'integer'],
            'name' => ['required_if:car,new', 'string'],
            'car_number' => ['required_if:car,new', 'required_without:no_number', 'unique:cars,c_number', 'digits_between:10,10'],

}
```

Edit 
I forget. Right now when I'm selecting new car and sending complete form it shows error under dropdown list to old cars that value must be integer.

Answer (score 0):

The order in the validation rules is importent, according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic) :

> **Stopping On First Validation Failure**
>
> Sometimes you may wish to stop running validation rules on an
>   attribute after the first validation failure. To do so, assign the
>   bail rule to the attribute:
>
> ```
> $request->validate([
>     'title' => 'bail|required|unique:posts|max:255',
>     'body' => 'required', ]);
> ```
>
> In this example, if the `unique` rule on the `title` attribute fails, the
>   `max` rule will not be checked. Rules will be validated in the order
>   they are assigned.

And in your case the first rule fails `'required_if:car,new',` you selected the new car radio button but you didn't give a value for the `car_number`.

So to fix the issue you have just to reverse the order of rules like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      $request->validate([            
            'car' => ['required_if:car,old', 'integer'],
            'name' => ['required_if:car,new', 'string'],
            'car_number' => ['required_without:no_number', 'required_if:car,new', 
                             'unique:cars,c_number', 'digits_between:10,10'],
}
```

Comment: Right now when I chose new car and  check the checkbox he show error from required_if:car,new.

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming HTTP request contains "nested" field data, you may specify these fields in your validation rules using "dot" syntax:

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'author.description' => 'required',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same issue when i need **required_if** and **required_without** in same time
i have product type **digital** and **physical** so **required_without** validation should work on when **type='physical'** but with '**required_without**' validation

[image]

```
public function rules() {     
         return [            
           'type' => ['bail', 'required', 'string', 'max:10'],
           'product_measure' => ['required_without:custom_product_measure', 'required_if:type,physical'],
           'custom_product_measure' => ['required_without:product_measure'],
]
    }
```